# Dynamically Detect Custom Class With Aptana Studio 3

Tags: php, html, aptana, dreamweaver

I used to be on `Dreamweaver`, but I have since really gotten into `Aptana` Studio 3. I have finally gotten the code coloring down correctly, but one thing I really miss from `Dreamweaver` is the dynamic discovery and completion using custom classes. I cannot figure out how to do that in `Aptana` Studio though. Here is what I mean:

With `Dreamweaver` I could create a file such as class.php

```
<?php 

class Test {

  function __construct(){
  }

  function something(){
    $var = "test";
    return $var;
  }

}

?>
```

And then I could include it in say index.php

```
<?php 
include_once("class.php");

$test = new Test();
echo $test->something;

?>
```

Once I included the class in my code and then typed "$test = new " `Dreamweaver` would then automatically popup "Test()" for me to chooose. And then of course any variables to pass along. Also, when I typed "$test->" `Dreamweaver` would also pop up a list of the functions within that class for me to choose from as well and it would do this dynamically.

So my question is "How do I get this same functionality with `Aptana` Studio 3?" I am currently using `Aptana` Studio with the remote explorer to open and edit files from a webserver. I have found a few suggestions via `Google` about using projects, but I am not really interested in projects right now. I just want to open the file and edit it and/or just create a new file directly on the server.

So, is there anyone out there who knows how to get `Aptana` Studio to dynamically detect custom classes and use them for code completion like `Dreamweaver` does?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: This feature works for me, but I am using a project. I don't know why you would not want to use projects - it is just a local copy of your file. You could always delete the local copy when you are done.

Comment: I love the idea of not having something extra on my computer that I don't need and I love the fact that Aptana can edit and save directly to the server. Plus, I'm not really sure how to take an existing site that I have online and bring that into a project with Aptana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting this in as an answer because it is too long for a comment.

It is nice that Aptana can edit and save to the server, though I haven't found it to be nearly as reliable as local saving (I sure don't count on it).

To make a project from an existing site (which I do frequently), you just find a spot on your computer you want to keep your files, make a folder (name it after your site, probably), then go into Aptana and choose `File > Import`. Under 'General' there is an option for 'Existing Folder as New Project'. Choose that, click next, Browse to the folder you made, check the box next to the Project Type you want (PHP probably) and hit Finish. This will create a project (which is just an empty folder so far. Then you probably want to link the Project to the remote Connection you have been using(1). Now you can pull down the files you want to work from (grab your includes too, if you want them indexed) and edit them and upload them just like you have been (Ctrl + Shift + U FTW).

Added bonus: now you can do global search and replace on everything you've downloaded.

Projects are a huge part of Aptana, they are really worth the disk space (at least to me) - especially since you don't have to make a complete copy of your site to use them.

1. Window > Show View > Project Explorer, expand the Project in this window and double click 'Connections' where you can show the Project which connection to use.

Comment: Many many thanks for the simple straight forward post you presented here. I followed these steps you posted and it worked the first time. Just one question though. When I click save does it automatically upload the file to the server like I used to do with Dreamweaver? If not, is there a way to set it to do that?

Comment: It does not automatically upload the file on save (I just wear my fingers out with the classic Ctrl + s, Ctrl + Shift + u) but there is an option in the Web Deployment Wizard to automatically sync changes that you could experiment with: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/FTP,+SFTP,+and+FTPS+Deployment

Comment: YOU are absolutely awesome! That works for me. It's not the solution I was originally wanting to get, but it works. Maybe there's not a solution for the way I was originally wanting, but you definitely got me working in the way I was used to with Dreamweaver. Kudos!! Thanks alot for all your help.

Comment: I think in order to get the code assist you are looking for, the IDE needs to have a local index of the code you are working from. There may be an IDE that will create a local index from a remote site, but it is sort of a strange combo that I haven't seen. I'm glad you've got something that works for you, and thank you for pointing out the remote file explorer to me - it makes a repetitive task of mine much easier!